# Uncheck all checkboxes inside alertdialog.builder after press cancel button

Tags: android

I have created on listview inside the alertdialog.builder i want to uncheck all the checkboxes after press cancel button but for me it is not clearing and also not giving the position of checked checkbox i don't know how to do it.

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.w("count0", ""+mAlCategoryNames.size());    


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.categorylist,R.id.xTvCategoryName, mAlCategoryNames, Home.this, getLayoutInflater()), null);
        builder.setTitle("CHOOSE CATEGORIES");

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        Log.w("Cancel",""+"Called");
                        Set<SavingCheckBoxState> keys=CategoryAdapter.mCheckMaps.keySet();
                        //checkAll(false);
                        // selected[which] = false;
                            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
                            ListView list =((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                            int size = list.getCount();


                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Add",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        mAlFilterCategory.clear();
                        Set<SavingCheckBoxState> keys = CategoryAdapter.mCheckMaps
                                .keySet();
                        mAlFilterCategory = new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (keys.size() > 0) {
                            Iterator<SavingCheckBoxState> it = keys.iterator();
                            mCategory_Name=it.toString();
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                SavingCheckBoxState data = it.next();

                                if (data.isSelected()) {
                                    Log.w("category name", data.getmCatgegoryName());
                                    mAlFilterCategory.add(data.getmCatgegoryName());
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

        builder.show();
```

Comment: For clear all checkbox just clear the Checkboox state data.setSelected() = false.